# Faster mathematical calculations using numpy and scipy

Tags: python, function, numpy, scipy

I am calculating distances between multiple points. The array `gals_pos` is very large (almost 100,000 points) and `sph_pos` has 20 points.

The issue is that it is a slow code. I want to make it fast since I will apply it to more than a billion points (array `gals_pos`).

I call the following part of the code to give me distances. First I call function named `distance_calc` and get the distance on x axis, then on y axis and on z axis. Then I use the `dx`, `dy` and `dz` to calculate the magnitude of the distance. Please suggest ways in which I can make it faster.

```
import numpy as np
import time

gals_pos = np.random.uniform(low = 0.0, high = 1000.0, size = (10000,3))
sph_pos = np.random.uniform(low = 0.0, high = 1000.0, size = (100,3))

max_axis_lim = 1000.0
min_axis_lim = 0.0
shift_position_constant = max_axis_lim/2

time_init = time.clock()

def distance_calc(gals_pos,sph_pos, axis):
    dxyzd = gals_pos[None, :, axis] - sph_pos[:, None, axis]
    #dxyzd_cdist = spatial.cdist(sph_pos, gals_pos, 'euclidean') #unusable here since we want to do axis subtraction for dx, dy and dz
    dxyzd[dxyzd>max_axis_lim] -= shift_position_constant
    dxyzd[dxyzd<min_axis_lim] += shift_position_constant
    return dxyzd

def dist_mag(dx,dy,dz):
    dist_m = np.sqrt(dx**2+dy**2+dz**2)
    return dist_m

dxx = distance_calc(gals_pos,sph_pos,0)
dyy = distance_calc(gals_pos,sph_pos,1)
dzz = distance_calc(gals_pos,sph_pos,2)

dist_d = dist_mag(dxx,dyy,dzz)

time_final = time.clock()
time = time_final-time_init
print "time taken = ", time

time taken = 0.11
```

Comment: In my opinion this kind of question is not well suited for SO. If you ask such a question, please add at least a code example by creating random data and show us the timings.

Comment: I have edited as you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Since you are just using straightforward `numpy` vector math, without iterations and such, there isn't an obvious way to speed this up.  You might be able to combine the 3 axis calcs into one, but I don't expect much of speed improvement.  Have you tried profiling?

Comment: Acting on all axis at once, `gals_pos[None, :, :] - sph_pos[:, None, :]` does not help.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, I have done profiling. The longest time taken in these steps is at the axis distance calculation part. This takes 0.005 seconds. If I can speed this up, it will be a great deal of help.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, there isn't much you can do to speed this up; although you may be able to gain up to a factor ten using numexpr using a few threads.

However, the bigger question is: do you really need all the pairwise distances? Unless you are writing your own gravity simulator, and are happy to go about it the brute-force manner, the answer is probably no. For calculating short-range interactions, such as for collision detection for instance, look at the functionality in scipy.spatial. It will be many orders of magnitude faster for typical problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I definitely need each pairwise distance.

Comment: Unless you have invented a new class of problems, you definitely don't.

Answer (score 0):

Look at scikit-learn. For example,

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html